# CSS style rule for div element belonging to multiple classes nested within another element's class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to create a style rule to apply the Border Box model to the div elements belonging to the following classes:

container, row, classes that begin with column, cell, and a elements,

all of which should be nested within div elements belonging to the cell class.

This is my code so far:

```
    div.cell > div.container div.row div[class^="column"]. div.cell div.a {box-sizing: border-box;}
```

Can someone please advise what i am missing?

Thanks so much

Comment: this part is weird `div[class^="column"]div.cell`: maybe you forget a space?

Comment: Why don't you apply it to all elements? It's so much easier. `*,*::before,*::after{box-sizing:border-box}`

Comment: Your code is way too specific and only targets the div with an a href around it (along with all the other conditions you attached to it). Use commas and then you can call out different conditions where the box model applies. I do agree that you might as well apply the border box model to your whole layout, any reason why you're not?

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks. You are correct that i forgot a space - i wanted to select all classes beginning with "column", as well as the cell class. I edited my original code

Comment: As @NathanielFlick pointed out, what you currently have would only apply to the last `div.a {}`. You need to actually write it out to be `div.cell > .container, div.cell > .row {}` and so forth.

Comment: @JakubMuda thanks. Good idea - based on my specific project i require a style rule targeting just those specific elements with the border box model

Comment: You can create a custom class and just add it where necessary. `.customClass{box-sizing:border-box}`. You can also do the opposite. Set `border-box` for all elements and `content-box` where required. Keep it simple.

Comment: @NathanielFlick thanks. Can you please show me how i can edit my code so that i can select div elements containing any of those classes, and not just those with a href around it?

Comment: Check out the upvoted answer below.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to create a style rule to apply the Border Box model to
>   the div elements belonging to the following classes:
>
> container, row, classes that begin with column, cell, and a elements,
>
> all of which should be nested within div elements belonging to the
>   cell class.

```
div.cell div.container,
div.cell div.row,
div.cell div[class^="column"],
div.cell div[class^="cell"],
div.cell a {

  box-sizing: border-box;

}
```

The moral of this story is:

*Write your selectors on separate lines, so you can see everything clearly.*

Answer (score -1):

You're missing commas between each definition if I'm understanding your question correctly. **edit** I just now realized why you had class^="column".

```css
.cell .container, .cell .row, .cell div[class^="column"], .cell a {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

I'll update my answer if this isn't what you're looking for.  Your question is very confusing especially with no HTML context.

Comment: `class^="column"` is certainly a valid selector. It selects all elements that have a class that start with `column` there are plenty of uses for it.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that.  I didn't understand his question completely.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Your edit of the the `class^="column"` is wrong. It should be `div[class^="column"]` because it's an attribute selector.

Comment: Yup, thanks for pointing that out.  Needed a little syntax refresher.

Comment: @BrettParsons Thanks. How do i indicate that each of those classes should be of the div element?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean.  Can you show your HTML?  Are you trying to select divs within the `.row`, `.cell`, ` etc?  Or only divs with those classes?  Do you have other elements that aren't divs with those classes?  It's best to try to keep your CSS from being too specific.

Comment: If you mean that you only want the divs with those classes and you have other elements with those classes, leave the div in front of the class.  `div.row` `div.cell` etc